# SQL Stored procedure extract data

Tags: sql, oracle11g, extract

Is this possible in a Oracle 11g SQL stored procedure? I need to get the data base on the `list.txt` with field ID. 1,3,5 to query in customer table and export the result in result.txt

Table name: **Customer**

```
ID|Name |Country
1 |Mark |USA
2 |Allan|UK
3 |James|USA
4 |Todd |UK
5 |Mike |UK
```

File: **list.txt**

```
ID
1
3
5
```

Result exported in text file

**result.txt**

```
1 |Mark |USA
3 |James|USA
5 |Mike |UK
```

Comment: Yes. It is possible (most things are).

Comment: Can you have the stored procedure for that?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: @marc_s database is Oracle 11g

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://nimishgarg.blogspot.in/2013/04/load-csv-file-in-oracle-using-plsql.html) link should help you read data from the **|** separated file. The example shows hw to read from a CSV, however it is just a matter of replacing the **,(comma)** character within the example with a **|(pipe)** character.

The link also contains a [reference](http://nimishgarg.blogspot.in/2011/09/create-csv-file-using-plsql.html) that shows how to create CSV files using PL-SQL. Again, here all you need to to do is to replace the **,(comma)** character within the example with a **|(pipe)** character.

Also, you need to ensure that you have permissions to read from and write to the folder locations that contain the text files you want to process.